# unable to receive push notification for Google calender

Tags: push-notification, google-calendar-api

I am trying to watch events resource based on given example using API explorer and Chrome Advanced Rest Client.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#watch_request_examples

**Requst**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/XXX%40gmail.com/events/watch?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZSNBYiHYPu6Y1_5P08hdb-EX5pdF4Ygj5ou_RKp_jOCS5beiDDH
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab",
 "type": "web_hook",
 "address": "https://www.example.com/WebHook/Index",
 "token": "token=123546"
}
```

**Response**

```
401 Unauthorized



cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  188
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 17 Oct 2013 12:49:00 GMT
expires:  Thu, 17 Oct 2013 12:49:00 GMT
server:  GSE
www-authenticate:  Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://www.example.com/WebHook/Index"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://www.example.com/WebHook/Index"
 }
}
```

- I have already whitelisted my domain www.example.com
- I have already got ssl certificate which is mandatory to receive push
  notifications
- I googled about this issue , but could not find much help.
- Posted same question on google group of calender api, but no response yet. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/ZHKwm2xWuNE

can anybody guide, whats wrong with request ?

Answer (score 0):

when you try with API Explorer,it will not use your OAuth2.0 project keys where you have registerd whitelisted domains, maybe it would use another keys

try to use client/lib

Answer (score 0):

Your auth token may be incorrect. Please make sure you are using correct auth token for the calendar you are trying to set watch for

Answer (score 0):

The one step I was missing to get this working was to actually enable the Calendar API in the console. The 401 push.webhookUrlUnauthorized error is really not helpful here.

Answer (score -3):

Finally It worked for me , cause of error "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel" was in Configuration of Project in

- Go to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
- Click your project name
- Click "API & Auth" Menu on left
- then click on sub menu "Push"
- Click on Add Domains button which Allows webhook notifications to be
  sent to the entered domains

Happy coding :)