# Google Calendar Push Notifications: Correct Domain Validation and Registration but Unable to receive notifications

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I'm facing an issue with Google Calendar Push Notifications. First I'd like to explain my scenario.

I'm trying to develop a java application to be integrated in a platform that handles sensors and actuators. The goal of this application is to use Google Calendar APIs and Push Notifications to follow a certain kind of events. My first "architecture" that I chose is the following ( I'm open to suggestions and criticism given my young experience as developper ;-) :

1. A simple Tomcat Servlet which will be the final webhook for Google Servers **(A)**;
2. A java class that implements a simple Server-Client Socket **(B)**;
3. A java class that uses Google Calendar API and receive push messages through one of its methods **(C)**;

The logic (maybe not so efficient) behind this structure is that Google Servers send notifications to my Tomcat webhook, which at the same time is the client of my Socket channel. When it receives pushes, it does its job and warns the Socket Server. The latter, thanks to a static object, invokes a method of **C**. This class will use Google APIs to check what's happened.

First and mandatory resource to study is: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

I've been able to complete **Step 1: Verify that you own the domain** using Webmaster Tools and add correctly my domain for push notifications as indicated in **Step 2: Register your domain** These two steps lead me to my first question:

**Does Google check whether the listed domains have valid SSL certificates during these two steps?**

My domain is something like "domain.com" and the full URL to reach the webhook is hhttps://ab.domain.com/app/notifications. There is a very important note in Google documentation:

> *Note that the Google Calendar API will be able to send notifications to this >HTTPS address only if there is a valid SSL certificate installed on your web >server. Invalid certificates include:*
>
> - Self-signed certificates.
> - Certificates signed by an untrusted source.
> - Certificates that have been revoked.
> - Certificates that have a subject that doesn't match the target
>   hostname.

First thing first, I've configured Tomcat to enable SSL and so HTTPS following the official documentation: *tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html .* Now I can access tomcat and my servlet through https.

The problem is that I can't receive "correctly" the push notifications. By using a browser plugin for simulating Http/Https request I can reach easily my Tomcat webhook and this one warns correctly my Java application. Therefore , since I can almost exclude problems about the Socket channel, I'm focusing on the communication between Google Servers and my Tomcat webhook.
I'm using Wireshark to see the incoming traffic from Google through the port 8443 (https for Tomcat). Obviously is encrypted, so I can't check a lot, but many packets are marked as PSH(push). However they seem to have a payload, which according to Google doc,they shouldn't because push notifications are just packets with headers info.

So my very first doubt is about the certificate. I don't have one, therefore I'm using this trial one from [Verisign.com](http://www.verisign.com/support/verisign-intermediate-ca/Trial_Secure_Server_Root/index.html) (which by the way is suggested in the Tomcat documentation for enabling SSL)

The very second doubt is about the validation and registration procedure. Even though I've managed to do it and Google is accepting the domain ab.domain.com/app/notifications as webhook, I don't have tools to prove that everything is correct.

I've found the following post in Stackoverflow: ["Unable to receive push notification for Google calender"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463049/unable-to-receive-push-notification-for-google-calender), ["Calendar push notification to java app engine backend servlet"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908836/calendar-push-notification-to-java-app-engine-backend-servlet), ["Google Calendar Push Notification watch command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930262/google-calendar-push-notification-watch-command-in-php) I've already verified the differents answers and suggestions and nothing changed.

What am I missing ? Thanks a lot, I would be grateful for any tip, hint, answer, pointer :-)

Comment: When you send watch request, did you get watch response with HTTP 200 ok status code? which indicates that the notification channel is set properly.

Comment: Hi SGC. Thank you for your comment, I forgot to mention it. Yes, when I send a watch request I always receive a correct status response with HTTP 200

Comment: @DemoomeD534 I'm also stuck in a similar kind of situation. Please let me know if you were able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to debug a webhook, either for mechanics (i.e. proper setup on the sender side) or correctness (examining the post payload) try using [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/). If possible, register both a RequestBin URL along with your intended destination URL. RequestBin will give you full visibility of what the payload is, as well as give you assurances that you've set things up properly on the sender (Google) side.

Comment: This won't work, you need to OWN the domain (and prove it through webmaster tools) to be able to receive push notifications. It really should be possible to use third party services during development/test, but this is not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a valid SSL ceritificate. Self-signed is not allowed.